# Slice multiple slices at once with tensorflow

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow

I am preparing the input tensor for the tensorflow RNN.
Currently I am doing the following

```
rnn_format = list()
for each in range(batch_size):
    rnn_format.append(tf.slice(input2Dpadded,[each,0],[max_steps,10]))
lstm_input = tf.stack(rnn_format)
```

Would it be possible to do this at once, without loop, with some tensorflow function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by Peter Hawkins, you can use `gather_nd` with the appropriate indices to get there.

Your uniform cropping on the inner dimension can simply be done before the call to `gather_nd`.

Example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

# integer image simply because it is more readable to me
im0 = np.random.randint(10, size=(20,20))
im = tf.constant(im0)

max_steps = 3
batch_size = 10

# create the appropriate indices here
indices = (np.arange(max_steps) +
    np.arange(batch_size)[:,np.newaxis])[...,np.newaxis]
# crop then call gather_nd
res = tf.gather_nd(im[:,:10], indices).eval()

# check that the resulting tensors are equal to what you had previously
for each in range(batch_size):
  assert(np.all(tf.slice(im, [each,0],[max_steps,10]).eval() == res[each]))
```

**EDIT**

If your slices indices are in a tensor, you simply replace numpy's operations with tensorflow's operations when creating `indices`:

```
# indices stored in a 1D array
my_indices = tf.constant([1, 8, 3, 0, 0])
indices = (np.arange(max_steps) +
    my_indices[:,tf.newaxis])[...,tf.newaxis]
```

Further remarks:

- `indices` is created by taking advantage of [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) during the addition: arrays are virtually tiled so that their dimensions match. Broadcasting is supported by numpy and by tensorflow in a similar fashion.
- Ellipsis `...` is part of the standard [numpy slicing notation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html), it basically fills all remaining dimensions left by the other slicing indices. So `[..., newaxis]` is basically equivalent to `expand_dims(·, -1)`.

Comment: Thanks - the np.expand_dims calls must be part of the graph however. I need to define operations that will be executed _on each_ input batch

Comment: I think you simply want to put the `tf.gather_nd(input[:,:10], indices)` operation in your graph. `indices` can remain an `np.array` as long as `max_steps` and `batch_size` values are known during graph construction.

Comment: Not sure, will test. Meanwhile, in my use case the indices I need are not consecutive that is  `for each in range(batch_size): index = some_int_tensor[each]`. Then `rnn_format.append(tf.slice(im, (index, 0), (max_steps, -1)))`.  So I need random indices in `im` array (due to shuffling). Does your construct handle this ? (Note that I basically select all the inner dimension)

Comment: Yep - so I need the operation in my graph cause it's not a continuous slice of the `im` - I really need to pick the (non consecutive) indices specified in `some_int_tensor`, that changes in each training example. It is actually a more general question than the original example. I'd really appreciate a solution to this ;)

Comment: I edited the answer to include the possibility to get indices from a tensor.

Comment: Well, this solves it :) Could you add some comments for instance explain why `np.arange(max_steps) + my_indices` adds a new column to indices with the elements of the first column incremented by max_steps - 1 (which is the desired result of course) ? This puzzles me a bit as `np.arange(max_steps)` gives me just an array (0,1,..., max_steps-1). Also the role of the ellipsis escapes me (I never really used numpy)

Answer (score 1):

Try `tf.split` or `tf.split_v`. See here:

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/split

Does that help?

Comment: It seems tf.split cannot give the overlapped slices.

Comment: Hmm. You didn't mention the slices need to be overlapped. One way you can do this (although it's a very big hammer for the job) is using `tf.gather`. You can build a list of indices describing each slice you want, and use `gather` to extract the corresponding data.

Comment: Thank you Peter. I will look at tf.gather and let you know the result.

Comment: I have researched about the tf.gather function but I couldn't find a way to specify the size of output slices as I could do in the tf.slice. Could you give me an example of the tf.gather where it is specified a size and begin indexes of the output slices?

Comment: Interested my self in a way to make gather (or gather_nd) do the job